# Update the ItemSource of a Datagrid from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid, dispatcher

I've seen many of these types of questions asked and answered here but none of those seems to solve my problem.

I have a Page that retrieves and shows a list of data from a database. my initial code looked like this

```
   private void HistoryPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //''''''
        _invoices = Invoice.GetAll(); // returns a list of invoices
         InvoiceList = new PagingCollection<Invoice>(_invoices, _itemsPerPage);
        DgInvoices.ItemsSource = InvoiceList.CurrentItems;
      //''''''''' 
    }
```

this worked ok until the data list got bigger. now it takes about 6-8 seconds for this operation.
then I tried to fetch data from a different thread and update the Datagrid ( DGInvoices ) from there.

```
   private void HistoryPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //''''''''

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            _invoices = Invoice.GetAll();
              InvoiceList = new PagingCollection<Invoice>(_invoices, _itemsPerPage);
            DgInvoices.ItemsSource = InvoiceList.CurrentItems;
        }).Start();
    }
```

which throws this exception

> The Calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

After searching around, I found that the Dispatcher is the way to go about this. but I cannot get it to work.

```
    private void HistoryPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //''''''''
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            _invoices = Invoice.GetAll();
              InvoiceList = new PagingCollection<Invoice>(_invoices, _itemsPerPage);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                DgInvoices.ItemsSource = InvoiceList.CurrentItems;
            });

        }).Start();
    }
```

this still throws the above exception.

can you recommend a way to get this working?

Comment: What is the type of Invoice. can you explain more about _invoices and PagingCollection<Invoice>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think a `BackgroundWorker` would be the best option. `Dispatcher` may work, but it's a more "forced" operation in WPF and it can sometimes present a litany of other problems. With a `BackgroundWorker` you can do your data work in the background, and then do your UI work on the main thread upon its completion.

As an example:

```cs
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Subscribe to the events
    bw.DoWork += Bw_DoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

private void HistoryPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Start background worker on page load
     bw.RunWorkerAsync(); //This is the DoWork function
}

//Background worker executes on separate thread
private void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     //Do long running operations
     _invoices = Invoice.GetAll();           
}

//Fires when the DoWork operation finishes. Executes on the main UI thread
private void Bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     //Update UI when the worker completes on the main thread
     InvoiceList = new PagingCollection<Invoice>(_invoices, _itemsPerPage);
     DgInvoices.ItemsSource = InvoiceList.CurrentItems;
}
```

If your operation gets really long you can even tap into the `BackgrounWorker.ReportProgess` operation and give status updates to the UI. It's a great tool for loading operations that you can use to avoid locking the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Dispatcher within new thread?

You can simply use Dipatcher outside of the new thread.

Like this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            DgInvoices.ItemsSource = InvoiceList.CurrentItems;
        });
```

So you can invoke on the main thread and not on the new thread

Comment: sorry  I updated the code, I have some pagination thing going on. so I need the InvoiceList object to be initialized before assigning it to Datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Don't update DgInvoices.ItemsSource directly inside the thread.
Instead bind ItemSource to a property and update the property in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Upon to your last edit, to get this working you must move
`InvoiceList = new PagingCollection<Invoice>(_invoices, _itemsPerPage)` to the `Dispatcher` too because its child `CurrentItems` is assigned to DitaGrid's items source. Thus, you cannot modify `InvoiceList` from other than main UI thread.

Additionally I suggest using `Task` instead of `Thread` because creating thread is too expensive operation and `Task` may reuse already created threads and save your time and PCs resources. `Task` is a smart wrapper of the `Thread`.

```charp
private void HistoryPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //''''''''
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _invoices = Invoice.GetAll();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            InvoiceList = new PagingCollection<Invoice>(_invoices, _itemsPerPage);
            DgInvoices.ItemsSource = InvoiceList.CurrentItems;
        });
    });
}
```

Or in case your API have async method to get the data you may use asynchronuous approach. But i dont's know if such awaitable method exists.

```charp
private async void HistoryPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //''''''''
    await _invoices = Invoice.GetAllAsync();
    InvoiceList = new PagingCollection<Invoice>(_invoices, _itemsPerPage);
    DgInvoices.ItemsSource = InvoiceList.CurrentItems;
}
```